# how to update the multiple nested sub document field status to true or false

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to update multiple nested sub document field which eid:`63b3f577763b3f5777` in the document status to true or false,

I try updateMany query but its not working...

I know my schema is more nested but i don't have any other option

this is my document model

```
{
"_id":"63b3b63b3f57774024"
"name":"dev"
"email":"dev@gmail.com"
"image":"https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com"

"tickets":[
{
"sid":"63b363b3f5777f5768"
"eid":"63b3f577763b3f5777"
"name":"john"
"status":false
_id:{
"$oid":"63b463b3f5777178c4"
}
},
{
"sid":"63b363b3f5777f5769"
"eid":"63b3f577763b3f5777"
"name":"viswam"
"status":false
"_id":{
"$oid":"63b463b3f5777178c5"
}
{
"sid":"63b63b3f57773f5770"
"eid":"63b3f577763b3f5777"
"name":"dev"
"status":false
"_id":{
"$oid":"63b63b3f57774178c6"
}
{
"sid":"63b63b3f57773f5771"
"eid":"63b3f577763b3f5777"
"name":"kumar"
"status":false
"_id":{
"$oid":"63b463b3f5777178c7"
}
""__v":0
}]
```

I need to update tickests.status to true or false.How to check this field?

Can anyone suggest me the exact query to find this?

Specification

- node: v14.17.3,
- mongoose: "^6.6.5",
- mongodb:Atlas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collections.updateMany
({"tickets.eid":"63b3f577763b3f5777"},
{"$set":{"tickets.$[elem].status":"false"}},
{"arrayFilters": [{"elem.eid":"63b3f577763b3f5777"}]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
db.collections.updateMany(
  { "tickets": { "$elemMatch": { "eid": "63b3f577763b3f5777" } } }
  { "$set": { "tickets.$.status": false } }
)
```

If you have any query. Please let me know

Comment: It's working but it updates the first matching element only but not many

Comment: your updated post have 2 different eid's but i have singe eid in multiple documents

Comment: Then use previous one.I am also using same code 
  { "tickets": { "$elemMatch": { "eid": "63b3f577763b3f5777" } } }